# Why prepend a character to both strings before comparing for equality with `[[` in bash?

Tags: bash, language-lawyer

I was looking at [the source code of NodeSource's installer script for Node.js](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x).

Everywhere in the code, when they want to compare two strings, they prepend `X` to both sides before comparing:

```bash
if [[ "X${NODENAME}" == "XNode.js 10.x" ]]; then
```

I was pointed to some questions on the network:

- [What's the purpose of adding a prefix on both sides of a shell variable comparison to a string literal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490393/163490)
- [Why do shell script comparisons often use x$VAR = xyes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174119/4135063)
- [Why append an extra character in `test`/`[` string comparison in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64436032/4135063)

They all explain why this is necessary when comparing with `[`. But in this case, the comparison is with `[[`.

Is this technique really necessary for `[[`?

Comment: It's an example of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  `[[ $NODENAME == 'Node.js 10.x' ]]` is perfectly safe (and a lot more readable).

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as duplicate. "Why prepend an x to comparisons" is not the same as "Do we need to prepend an x when comparing with [[".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Credits to @danielhoherd, in a comment</sub>

No, it's not necessary.

In fact, this technique is outdated for `[` as well, as explained in the [SC2268 shellcheck rule](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2268):

> ##### Avoid x-prefix in comparisons as it no longer serves a purpose.
>
> [...]
>
> Some older shells would get confused if the first argument started with a dash, or consisted of `!` or `(`. As a workaround, people would prefix variables and values to be compared with `x` to ensure the left-hand side always started with an alphanumeric character.
>
> POSIX ensures [this is not necessary](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), and all modern shells now follow suit.
>
> [...]

Comment: Note the "results are unspecified" for more than 4 arguments in the linked POSIX spec. Avoiding `-a` and `-o` to combine larger groups of operators is part and parcel of staying clear of ambiguous cases (where `(` and `)` can be improperly parsed as test syntax rather than values).